# Less extract negative value from sprite

Tags: less

I have sprite image declared like this

```
@ok: -10px, -1370px, 40px, 40px;
```

and I want to get height of sprite like this

```
extract(@ok,3)
```

this is working fine but when I want negative value

```
-extract(@ok,3)
```

this not gonna be parsed

```
- extract(@ok,3)
```

this is parsed as `- 40px` which is not valid

only way which is valid is

```
0 - extract(@ok,3)
```

but I don't like it. Is there way how to do it other way??

Comment: did you try '-'extract(@ok,3) ?

Comment: I always write it as `extract(@ok, 3) * -1`. `-extract(@ok, 3);` will actually be parsed (with the master Less compiler at least) but it obviously means "call `-extract` function".

Comment: as i understand the question well, it has nothing to do with the Less extract function. The real question is how to assign the negative of a posive value? `1 -value` or `value * -1`?